# How can I double the newlines in an output stream

Tags: text-processing

When I have an output stream:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

How can I double the newlines:

```
a

b

c

d

e
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
sed G
```

is a [well known one-liner](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sed1line.txt) for that.

Performance-wise, the most effective with the standard Unix tool chest would probably be:

```
paste -d '\n' - /dev/null
```

If you don't want to add an empty line after the last line:

```
sed '$!G'
```

To add the empty lines *before* the input lines:

```
paste -d '\n' /dev/null -
```

Or:

```
sed 'i\
/'
```

Comment: To complete the list  `awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\n\n"}1' file` :)

Answer (score 6):

using `pr`: Paginating Files

```
pr -t -d file.txt
```

output:

```
a

b

c

d

e
```

using `awk`:

```
awk '{printf("%s\n\n",$0)}' file.txt
```

Comment: This has already been proposed by @don_crissti

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas don_crissti's answer was only gone for 5 minutes and restored (with the pipe) 15 minutes before the original (`pr` only) answer here appeared, hence my remark. (deleted `2014-11-03 21:00:34Z`, restored `2014-11-03 21:05:34Z` first version of this answer: `2014-11-03 21:21:44Z`)

Answer (score 5):

With `awk` you can define the Output Record Separator as double new line:

```
awk -v ORS="\n\n" 1 file
```

Then, `1` performs the default `awk` action: `{print $0}`, that is, print the current line.

Answer (score 4):

While `sed` is the obvious choice, another very reliable candidate might be `dd`.

It is probably more useful for situations in which it is the byte-count that matters more than it is the line-count, but *block*ing and *unblock*ing data is what it does best:

```
seq 10| dd cbs=16 conv=block                             
1               2               3               4               5               6               7               8               9               10
```

That, so far, is more like achieving the opposite of what you've asked, but `dd` can *block* lines on spaces - it will translate input `\n`ewlines into spaces and pad those lines on `cbs=[num]` bytes of spaces. And so if you can reliably predict a maximum byte-length per line *(because guessing too low will result in truncation)*, and then double that figure...

```
seq 10| dd cbs=16 conv=block | dd cbs=8 conv=unblock

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10
```

...you can then *unblock* it on half the `cbs` - which will trim trailing spaces and print a `\n`ewline every `cbs=[num]` bytes. This is much more useful for handling *large* volumes of possibly binary data *(or for terminal input)* than it would be for ordinary text files, but it is an alternative - and can definitely compete *(on the large scale)* in the performance department with just about anything.

Another specialized alternative might be `nl` and `tr`. This would only be useful if your input resembles that shown - because the solution involves `tr`anslating spaces into `\n`ewlines. In any case, `nl` will always insert at least `-w`idth +1 bytes of spaces at the head of each line it is passed - whether or not it numbers them. And so you can...

```
printf %s\\n a b c d e |
nl -bn |
tr -s \  \\n
```

...which prints:

```
a

b

c

d

e
```

The `-bn` switch instructs `nl` *not* to number the body of its input, but it still inserts 6 spaces by default - and at least two even with a `-w1` argument. This can make it useful for other cases as well - such as...

```
INPUT |nl -bn -w1 |sed '/address/s/  //...' | sed '/^  /!...'
```

...in which the second `sed` always knows which lines the first has touched. But I digress...

Anyway, `tr` `-s`queezes all incoming sequences of spaces into a single byte and `tr`anslates each result into a `\n`ewline. Without the `-s` switch there would be six new intervening `\n`ewlines between each alphabetic above. And that can be reliably set as easily as `-w1`.

Still, I would use `sed`. And speaking of which, though the `G`et commands and `i`nsert commands have already been mentioned, there are also the `a`ppend and `c`hange commands for that. Doing either would look like this:

```
printf %s\\n a b c d e|
sed 'a\
'
```

```
a

b

c

d

e
```

`sed G` works because it `G`ets the contents of the `H`old buffer appended to the pattern buffer following a `\n`ewline. `H`old space is, by default, empty, and so all you get is a `\n`ewline. But, in case there is more to the `sed` script and the `H`old buffer is *not* empty, then you can always `a`ppend any string at all to any line, or else you can `p`rint the line then `c`hange it on output like:

```
INPUT| sed '...;p;c\
'
```

...with GNU `sed` the actual newline is not required for `i`, `c`, or `a` and all three can be used like `sed '[aic]\\'` though maybe that is a bad habit to adopt. In any case, any one of those three is likely less costly performance-wise than a `s///`ubstitution because none imply a regex pattern, though I doubt if the difference is at all significant.

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe through `sed`:

```
.... | sed 's/$/\n/'
```

Comment: Is it just me, or you've really asked the question just to answer it by yourself? :D

Comment: @MartinBeseda yes, the question came up on chat and was claimed to already been answered. Answering own questions is perfectly valid.

Comment: `sed G` would be more canonical - see [Famous sed one-liners explained](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/)

Comment: @steeldriver put that up as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: That is not standard syntax. On the right hand side of the `s` command, portably (and POSIXly), you need a backslash followed by a literal newline character.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas So this is a GNU `sed` extension?

Comment: [That's also in the sed FAQ](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq4.html#s4.1)

Answer (score 3):

Using perl you can add a newline before

```
...|perl -pe 's/^/\n/'
```

or after each line:

```
...|perl -pe 's/$/\n/'
```