# How to insert multiple blank lines after every line

Tags: sed, awk, solaris

I want to insert 5 blank lines after every line in my input file.

`foo.txt`:

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

`out.txt`:

```
line 1





line 2





line 3    





...
```

Solaris 5.10, `nawk` or `sed`.

Comment: See also [How can I double the newlines in an output stream](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/165766)...

Answer (score 16):

That's the job for `sed`:

```
sed -e 'G;G;G;G;G' file
```

With `awk`:

```
nawk -vORS='\n\n\n\n\n\n' 1 file
```

Or shorter version:

```
awk 'ORS="\n\n\n\n\n\n"' file
```

or avoid setting `ORS` for each input line:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\n\n\n\n\n\n"};1' file
```

Comment: Or this variant: `awk 'ORS="\n\n\n\n\n\n"'`

Comment: Or this variant: `sed 's/$/\n\n\n\n\n/g' file`

Comment: @Dani_l: It only works in GNU sed

Comment: @cuonglm didn't know that, thanks for the info. Which part is gnu specific? the \n in replacement?

Comment: @Dani_l: Yes, `\n` in the replacement part of `s///`.

Comment: `awk 'ORS="\n\n\n\n\n\n"'` may be shorter (good for golfing, and handy-ish for quick one-offs), but it is unnecessarily setting a variable for every record it processes.

Comment: @Peter.O: Good point. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Another one , with printf

`cat file.txt |  xargs printf "%s\n\n\n\n\n"`

To output that to a file

`(cat file.txt |  xargs printf "%s\n\n\n\n\n") > out.txt`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use `nl` for this, too. It comes to my mind because when I do stuff like that I often find it useful to retain the original line-numbers.

```
eval "nl -ba -s'$(printf "\n\n\n\n\n'")" <infile
```

Also `pr` is spec'd for the `-d`oublespace argument - which will double all newlines in input on output.

But `sed`'s good, too.