# Paste texts on alternate lines

Tags: linux, text-processing, text-formatting

Let's say there are two files, "main" and "rename".
The file "rename" has a few lines with names for appending on 
the alternate rows of file "main". (according to the position in the "rename")

I has been using `paste` for concatenating lines from different files, but I was stucked on this case.

Is there any other ways of doing this without using copy and paste?
(Preferably with the command that can be readily used in Ubuntu Linux 18.04.)

file "main"

```
#
stars
#
twinkle
#
on
#
the
#
sky
```

file "rename"

```
yellow
white
green
red
blue
```

desired output

```
#yellow
stars
#white
twinkle
#green
on
#red
the
#blue
sky
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Awk` by processing both the files, by keeping one file contents in the system memory and other as we iterate over it.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ words[NR]=$0; next}{ if ($0 ~ /^#/) $0 = $0 words[++idx];  print }' rename main
```

A brief explanation of how it works

- The part `FNR==NR{ words[NR]=$0; next}` operates on the first file `rename` by indexing your file contents in the array `words`. `NR` is a special variable in `Awk` which tracks the current line number. So the array becomes something like `words['1']="yellow", words['2']="white"`
- The part `{..}` after now works on the next file `rename` and if the line matches `#` we update the current line `$0` by appending the element from the array created.
- The `print` command prints the line with string appended after `#`, for those lines starting with it, and other lines as-is.

Answer (score 1):

This is rather easily done with a single `paste` invocation

```
<main paste -d '\0\n' - rename -
#yellow
stars
#white
twinkle
#green
on
#red
the
#blue
sky
```

When multiple delimiters are used in the delimiter list passed to `-d`, `paste` uses these delimiters consecutively until they're exhausted and then starts over with them again.
In the above command the two delimiters passed are `\0` (empty string) and `\n`(newline). Standard input is pointed to the `main` file, which is then referenced within the command twice via the two `-`'s, all leading to a line of output to form by

1. taking a line from `main` and
2. adding to it an empty string
3. taking the next line from `rename` and adding it to the above
4. then adding a newline to the above
5. finishing the cycle by adding a line from
   `main`

And so on

Comment: Thanks for improvement on the paste solution ... cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that uses **paste**. First to double-space the second file, so that interesting lines are in parallel. Second to paste those lines together using a value \0 or NUL, which essentially does not appear as whitespace. We can use a number of schemes to double-space the output, but paste is convenient (such as **sed** as noted, *for others see [How can I double the newlines in an output stream](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165766/how-can-i-double-the-newlines-in-an-output-stream) ).

The display of the two original files suggests the alignment that double-spacing can accomplish. The paste of the two files using the default separator simply shows that alignment. The real answer is presented in two ways, a standard way using a temporary file, the second using process substitution.

Here is the script snippet:

```
FILE1=${1-data1}
shift
FILE2=${1-data2}
E="expected-output"

# Utility functions: print-as-echo, print-line-with-visual-space.
pe() { for _i;do printf "%s" "$_i";done; printf "\n"; }
pl() { pe;pe "-----" ;pe "$*"; }

pl " Input $FILE1 and $FILE2, columnized to save visual space:"
paste $FILE1 $FILE2 | expand -30

pl " Expected output:"
cat $E

rm -f t0
pl " Results, paste with double-space $FILE2, default options:"
# sed '/^$/d;G' $FILE2 > t0
paste -d '\n' - /dev/null < $FILE2 > t0
paste $FILE1 t0

pl " Results with paste of NUL, \0:"
paste -d'\0' $FILE1 t0

pl " Results with paste, process substitution:"
paste -d'\0' $FILE1 <( sed '/^$/d;G' $FILE2 )
```

producing:

```
 Input data1 and data2, columnized to save visual space:
#                             yellow
stars                         white
#                             green
twinkle                       red
#                             blue
on                            
#                             
the                           
#                             
sky                           

-----
 Expected output:
#yellow
stars
#white
twinkle
#green
on
#red
the
#blue
sky

-----
 Results, paste with double-space data2, default options:
#       yellow
stars
#       white
twinkle
#       green
on
#       red
the
#       blue
sky

-----
 Results with paste of NUL, \0:
#yellow
stars
#white
twinkle
#green
on
#red
the
#blue
sky

-----
 Results with paste, process substitution:
#yellow
stars
#white
twinkle
#green
on
#red
the
#blue
sky
```

THis was done on a system like:

```
OS, ker|rel, machine: Linux, 3.16.0-7-amd64, x86_64
Distribution        : Debian 8.11 (jessie) 
bash GNU bash 4.3.30
paste (GNU coreutils) 8.23
```

cheers, drl